# Git checkout <branch_name> is not working

Tags: git, github

I am aware that git checkout -b "branch_name" will create a new branch and git checkout "branch_name" will switch to the specified branch

But when I unknowingly did git checkout branch_name (P.S there is no quotes surrounding the branch_name) even though it said it is tracking the specified branch I was not able to see the branch level changes.

So are the double quotes mandatory for specifying the branch name during checkout ?

Comment: The quotes are not mandatory. Something else is wrong. You'll need to provide more details about the "missing" changes for us to know what.

Comment: `git checkout branch_name` in the 2nd paragraph will not create a new branch, did you mean `git checkout -b branch_name`?

Comment: Could you explain what "the branch level changes" refers to, and what you were looking at that you expected to show them to you?

Comment: the quotes are immaterial during checkout.  You wouldn't be able to see any changes, if there were no changes made to that branch. try to retrieve current branch `git branch -a`

Comment: Apologies for the delayed response. It was due to a bug in IntelliJ. When I restarted it everything started working as normal. So no need of resolution. Anyways Thank you all for your time and efforts. Apologies once again for the inconvenience caused if any

Answer (score 0):

> is the double quotes mandatory for specifying the branch name during checkout ?

No, `"` is not needed.

From `git checkout`'s [reference](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout#_examples):

> `$ git checkout master`
>
> `$ git checkout mytopic`

Answer (score -1):

I have never used quotes for checking out a git branch in 4 years of using git. That being said, you can also do, in case you have a reason for doing so.

```
git checkout \"branch_name\"
git checkout -b \"branch_name\"
```